# Converting SQL Month from numerical to full written form

Tags: sql, sql-server

the following bit of SQL pulls through the month a marriage took place numerically, but i need to display the full written name of the month.... any ideas?

```
(SELECT RIGHT('00'+CAST(MONTH(MARDATE) AS VARCHAR),2)
 FROM MatterDataDef
 WHERE ptMatter = $Matter$)
```

Note - it might be microsoft sql server, but i'm not au fait with SQL

Comment: Where is the button located that turns on the emergency flashers of my car?  I don't know what kind of car it is.  In other words, you need to provide a little more information since the functions that do date formatting vary from system to system.

Comment: where would one find this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [datename](http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2008/04/datename-function-in-sql-server-2005.html) function, if it's SQL Server:

You con't need your concatenation `'00'+` or `cast` (assuming `mardate` is a datetime).

```
select datename(month,  MARDATE)
from ....
```

This shold execute without error.

**EDIT**
Edited the above code. You don't need the 'month()' conversion.

Comment: Just realised, you don't need the month conversion